# removing typo from css strangely messes up display

Tags: html, css

While trying to troubleshoot a problem I'm having with a project, I noticed that there was a random '/' appearing in my css file. Upon removing it, it actually made part of the border disappear in Firefox, and even more of it disappear in Chrome... I've stripped down the code to the bare essentials trying to figure out the problem, and still can't figure it out. I've narrowed the root of the problem down to the 'items' class in my css, but don't understand what's wrong with it, as when I validate just that class it doesn't throw any errors.

Here is how it is displaying with the slash removed:
http://jsfiddle.net/NrYws/2/

And here it is with the slash in the place it was before I removed it, and how it displays properly (in both FF and Chrome)... 
http://jsfiddle.net/NrYws/3/

Moving the slash to a different spot in the file (i.e. above the outerContainer class) results in the bad display. When I remove the 'items' class altogether, it works fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/NrYws/4/

I know it seems like the items class isn't necessary right now, but its just because I have stripped everything down to the bones to try to fix this, and is needed for the actual project.

Any ideas as to what's going on here? I'm sure its something painfully obvious that I'm just over-looking....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as if it deleted the first paragraph `.items`. Remove it and it displays correctly.

Removing solely `overflow: hidden` in `.items` works as you want it to work, I believe.

Though if `overflow: hidden` is required for whatever you're doing, we're going to need more that just this code to propose you a fix that works as you expect it to work.

Comment: It was producing a syntactical error that disable anything until the first closing bracket. Don't forget to mark the question as solved :) (and to upvote the good answers :) )

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the info!! And just waiting for the time to elapse before it lets me select an answer, didn't know it made me wait 8 minutes! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Because it removes the

```
.items
{
     float: left;
     height:180px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

you can delete it

Answer (score 1):

Remove overflow:hidden from items class as it is clipping outercontainer border.

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NrYws/8/

Here is a explanation about backslash in css: http://www.webteacher.ws/2005/01/22/490/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `overflow: hidden` or set height to 184px if you need to use overflow

```
.items
{
    float: left;
    height:184px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```